# Can't create azure linked service with python

Tags: python, azure, blob, azure-data-factory

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to create an azure data factory pipeline to copy and paste file from a blob to a blob or from a blob to a data lake.

**What i did**

I just followed the tutorial on Microsoft's website, i already have an ADF and blob so i didn't create it again, i'm now trying to create an Azure linked service, so i used this code:

```
# Create an Azure Storage linked service
ls_name = 'storageLinkedService'

# IMPORTANT: specify the name and key of your Azure Storage account.
storage_string = SecureString('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storageaccountname>;AccountKey=<storageaccountkey>')

ls_azure_storage = AzureStorageLinkedService(connection_string=storage_string)
ls = adf_client.linked_services.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, ls_name, ls_azure_storage)
print_item(ls)
```

But when i run it, i obtain this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-173-cabc65dd11b9>", line 4, in <module>
    ls = adf_client.linked_services.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, ls_name, ls_azure_storage)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\azure\mgmt\datafactory\operations\linked_services_operations.py", line 170, in create_or_update
    raise models.ErrorResponseException(self._deserialize, response)

ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Not Found'
```

I don't know why do i get this error. 
Does anyone have an idea ?

**Update**

I tried to skip this step and tried to create and file in the blob with this command: `adf_client.datasets.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, ds_name, ds_azure_blob)`

I got the same error `ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Not Found'` which lead me to think that the problem is related to the blob maybe.

Comment: Any progress now?

Comment: Still not able to do it. I'll try to replace client id and secret by my azure account connection ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue but failed.

I do not have an ADF so I followed the official tutorial to create Data Factory and Linked service, no error occurred.

main function

```
def main():

    # Azure subscription ID
    subscription_id = '***'

    # This program creates this resource group. If it's an existing resource group, comment out the code that creates the resource group
    rg_name = '***'

    # The data factory name. It must be globally unique.
    df_name = '***'

    # Specify your Active Directory client ID, client secret, and tenant ID
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='***', secret='***', tenant='***')
    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

    rg_params = {'location':'eastus'}
    df_params = {'location':'eastus'}

    # create the resource group
    # comment out if the resource group already exits
     resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(rg_name, rg_params)

     Create a data factory
     df_resource = Factory(location='eastus')
     df = adf_client.factories.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, df_resource)
     print_item(df)
     while df.provisioning_state != 'Succeeded':
         df = adf_client.factories.get(rg_name, df_name)
         time.sleep(1)

    # Create an Azure Storage linked service
    ls_name = 'storageLinkedService'

    # IMPORTANT: specify the name and key of your Azure Storage account.
    storage_string = SecureString('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=***;AccountKey=***')

    ls_azure_storage = AzureStorageLinkedService(connection_string=storage_string)
    ls = adf_client.linked_services.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, ls_name, ls_azure_storage)
    print_item(ls)
```

> ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Not
>   Found'

I think you could check the arguments if you have a mistake in it or if the service exists.(df,resource group, storage account)

Any concern ,please feel free to let me know.

---

***Update Answer:***

I created my own application registration in Azure AD on portal.

[image]

Application ID as below is your `client_id`

[image]

Create your `secret` and remember to write it down because it will hide later.

[image]

Directory Id as below is `tenant ID`

[image]

---

***Update Answer 2:***

I'm also a contributor role, so I think it's not a role issue.
I tried to change the ra_name(resource group) in the parameter to a nonexistent value, reproduced your exception successfully .

Please check again if your resource group or other parameters exist.

[image]

---

***Just for summary:***

It seems that ADF V1 and V2 does not support West Europe Region currently.

[image]

[image]

However , the **Supported regions** chapters in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction) have not been updated. That bothers you so long. You could re-create ADF and follow your original code to create link service.

Comment: i checked my argumetns but it stils doesn't work can't understand why

Comment: where do you find the informations about client id secret id tenant id ?

Comment: @OrhanYazar Please see my update answer. I show you how to get the client id ,secret  and tenant id.

Comment: Thank you for your update, i'll try to duplicate the exact things you did

Comment: still not, i wonder if i don't have permission prohibition, i'm gonna check it and come back to you asap

Comment: @OrhanYazar ok. waiting for your reply.

Comment: this is incredible, i'm not able to do it, still have the error `ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Not Found'` Do you know if i need to be owner on the blob storage and adf ? Because currently i'm just contributor for these both app.

Comment: i checked my ressource group and it exists, i also created a new blob in the same ressource group than my adf v2 but still the same problem, i don't get why, it recognizes my client id, tenant id etc.. but when i try to create the linked service, it doesn't work.

Comment: @OrhanYazar Your exception is "Not found", so I assume that the arguments are not written right, not a permission issue.

Comment: My blob is a V1 blob, do you think that i need to create a V2 blob ?

Comment: @OrhanYazar Does your data factory exist too? Did you create linked Service without exist Dada factory?

Comment: Yes i also already created it manually, and it's a V2 like written in the tuto on MS's platform

Comment: Ok Jay, i think that i found the problem ..., when we created the ADF V2, it was available in west europe, and i started to trying to create pipeline with python some week after the creation, but now, i found here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/v2/ that it's no longer available in west europe but it's in North europe, so it may solve my problem

Comment: @OrhanYazar Yes. I made a summary in my answer.You could mark the answer for others' reference on the forum. Thx.

Comment: Yes, i saw it Jay, when you chose the V1 and then chose V2, the list is updated and we can see that there is only East US. Thank you for your help =)